# Recommended reading material for getting started with webOS/Mojo SDK development?

Tags: javascript, json, palm-pre, mojo

I am starting to delve into the world of webOS and the Mojo SDK and having a great time so far, but I find myself having to constantly take a detour and read up on different subjects such as JSON, JavaScript, etc.  I realize now that instead of diving in head first I probably should have done some reading on the core technologies behind webOS, and so I turn to the stackoverflow community for some advice.

I am looking for some recommendations on reading material (or any resources, really) related to JavaScript, and webOS development in general.  The Palm developer site hasn't been too wonderful thus far.  I've messed with JavaScript a tiny bit, but am definitely still a beginner when it comes to that realm.

Comment: How much Java is involved with webOS? I thought it was HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Are you talking about using Java for the server or on the device?

Comment: Bleh, I never use them and always interchange the two terms even though they are completely separate technologies.  Fixing the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read some JavaScript books, and the book [Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141) is quite good. Despite the name, it goes into detail about basics too, so it is suitable to JavaScript beginners. However, it is a little lacking in not talking about the DOM much: You won't learn many tricks regarding working with HTML documents, but it's a good book to teach you JavaScript as a language and various useful techniques.

Answer (score 2):

I picked up the following from O'Reilly:

- [Palm WebOS](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596155261)
- [Javascript - The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/)

Also, online you can check out:

- http://developer.palm.com/
- http://www.webos-internals.org/wiki/Main_Page
- http://www.precentral.net/
- http://www.webosboston.org/
- http://www.webos-internals.org/wiki/Resources

Comment: +1 for Javascript - The Good Parts. Very popular around the Palm campus.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say learn JavaScript, CSS, and HTML in a browser. WebOS leverages your skills on the client side of the web, so aim to get those skills.

Check out the "best JavaScript book" threads, of which there are several.